# Pyspark iterate over dataframe by group on lookup of previous row

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

Please help me in this I am new to spark. Below is mydataframe

```
type col1 col2 col3
1    0    41   0
1    27   0    0
1    1    0    0 
1    183  0    2
2    null 0    0
2    null 10   0
3    0    126  0
3    2    0    1
3    4    0    0
3    5    0    0
```

Below should be my output

```
type col1 col2 col3 result
1    0    41   0    0
1    27   0    0    14
1    1    0    0    13
1    183  0    2    -168
2    null 0    0
2    null 10   0
3    0    126  0    0
3    2    0    1    125
3    4    0    0    121
3    5    0    0    116
```

The challenge is this has to be done for every group of type column the formula is like prev(col2)-col1+col3

I tried to use window and lag function on col2 to populate result column but it did not work.

Below was my code

```
part = Window().partitionBy().orderBy('type')
DF = DF.withColumn('result',lag("col2").over(w)-DF.col1+DF.col3)
```

Now I am struggling to try with map function please help

Comment: your logic `prev(col2)-col1+col3` doesn't match with the expected output.

Comment: Yes Ramesh agree it has to be prev(result)-col1+col3 . But how do we take col2 41 value and subtract with col1 27 ? . So was thinking on these lines and thought lag(col2) will fix dynamically but I miserably failed . Trying to think more but no clues I am getting

Comment: @user3292373 prev(result)-col1+col3 does not match either. The second row becomes -27 using this, not 14.

Comment: please tell how do we achieve this I should be getting the output as 41-27+0=14 for next row it has to take 14-1+0=13 and 13-183+2=-168 this has to be repetitive for every group of type 1,2 and 3 .

Comment: 13-183+2 = 172 not 168. is it true?

Comment: Not Ramesh it has to be -168 left to right precedence

Comment: my mistake :) sorry

Comment: prev(col2) + prev(results) + col3 - col1?

Comment: Thanks Shaido . Ur logic will work during implementation should I take lag of both columns. For now the approach is I am trying to add empty column using lit that is result then creating an new column for col2 that lags by 1 named it as col2_new, Now I am applying the formual that u mentioned it was not working. Is my approach ryt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is a bit tricky and complex.

You can do the following in `pyspark`

**pyspark**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
import sys
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy("type")
df = df.withColumn('result', F.lag(df.col2, 1).over(windowSpec) - df.col1 + df.col3)
df = df.withColumn('result', F.when(df.result.isNull(), F.lit(0)).otherwise(df.result))
df = df.withColumn('result', F.sum(df.result).over(windowSpec.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, -1)) + df.result)
df = df.withColumn('result', F.when(df.result.isNull(), F.lit(0)).otherwise(df.result))
```

**scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy("type")
df.withColumn("result", lag("col2", 1).over(windowSpec) - $"col1"+$"col3")
  .withColumn("result", when($"result".isNull, lit(0)).otherwise($"result"))
  .withColumn("result", sum("result").over(windowSpec.rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, -1)) +$"result")
  .withColumn("result", when($"result".isNull, lit(0)).otherwise($"result"))
```

You should have the following result.

```
+----+----+----+----+------+
|type|col1|col2|col3|result|
+----+----+----+----+------+
|1   |0   |41  |0   |0.0   |
|1   |27  |0   |0   |14.0  |
|1   |1   |0   |0   |13.0  |
|1   |183 |0   |2   |-168.0|
|3   |0   |126 |0   |0.0   |
|3   |2   |0   |1   |125.0 |
|3   |4   |0   |0   |121.0 |
|3   |5   |0   |0   |116.0 |
|2   |null|0   |0   |0.0   |
|2   |null|10  |0   |0.0   |
+----+----+----+----+------+
```

**Edited**

the first `withColumn` applies the formula `prev(col2) - col1 + col3`. The second `withColumn` changes *null to 0* for `result` column. The third `withColumn` is for *cumulative sum* i.e. adding all the values until the current row of result column. so the three `withColumn` is equivalent to `prev(col2) + prev(results) 1 col1 + col3`. The last `withColumn` is changing the *null values to 0* in `result` column.

Comment: Thanks alot for your efforts Ramesh. I am trying to understand what does Long.MinValue do so that I can replicate in pysaprk

Comment: I have edited with the working code for pyspark as well :) please have a look :)

Comment: Thanx alot bro I tried with various combinations of max.size the one you pinged worked for me . Thanx once again. Can you please explain me the sys.maxsize and those last three lines of code . I am very much eager to know

Comment: i have explained it. :) thanks for the upvote and acceptance :)

Comment: Dear Ramesh, I don't understand what is happening each time when I run above logic I get different values in stock now . No change was made to data Ramesh. Really dnt know what to do. I am seeing problem with rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, -1)) not understanding this one Ramesh. Please help

Comment: Solved it Ramesh.windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy("id") order by given as Id and the id column is unique id. and second change is have given F.lag(df.col2, 0,0). It worked

Comment: great to hear that @user3292373 :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, I have a question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964179/pyspark-mapping-multiple-variables thanks in advance! And regarding your code here, so you're using `withColumn` similar to a `case when` in sql ?